# Can't Add a One to Many RelationShip

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

In Order to Optimise code, I m trying to add a one to many relationship between CreateSessions and Operations entites .

**CreateSessions 1--* Operations**

So I added Foreign Key in  Operations entity to Link CreateSessionId, running the project i get this error :

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Operations_dbo.CrateSessions_CrateSessionId' on table Operations may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

This error is described in [microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/es-bo/help/321843/error-message-1785-occurs-when-you-create-a-foreign-key-constraint-tha)

What i understand is that the error is triggred because there are already a path with foreign keys from CrateSessions entity to Operations entity , which can be viewed in SqlServer Diagram  as the entity TicketOffices.

Is there a solution to make this One to Many relationShip , or it is impossible in this context ?
[image: RelationShip]

## Update

I found a smilare issue [here](https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/29937651/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths) , the Solution was disabling cascade delete OnModelCreating:

```
  modelBuilder
    .Entity<VendorDetails>()
    .HasOptional(e => e.State)
    .WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

So if I do that for Operations, deleting a CrateSession object won't trigger the Delete Of Operations  ?

Comment: The problem is you have `CASCADE` a that will cause cycles (not the foreign key itself); you can't do that as the error tells you. The error message is telling you exactly what you need to do here; what about the error don't you understand and we can try to explain further, but it is very specific here.

Comment: What don't you like about the solutions given to you by the error message itself? *"Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints."*

Comment: Show us the C# you're trying to "optimize " - i'm not really understanding why `crateSession.TicketOffice.Operations` offers you anything over `crateSession.Operations`

Comment: "Specify On DELETE No ACTION", means that if i would  delete a CrateSession the Operation wouldn't be deleted ?
what is the cycle that could happen that isn't clear

Comment: the problem here is not that of a cycle, but that of multiple cascade paths, namely cratesessions->ticketoffices, cratesessions->operations->ticketoffices.